# Is there any way to set line item status in an order?

Tags: 7, commerce

I want set line item status that if a line item is delivered. In an order, order status is for all the items but line item status is for each product.

Is there any module or something in UI?

I am using [drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a custom module for this, used hook_field_widget_form_alter and insert data in custom table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Commerce Delivery](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_delivery) module... It supports line items delivery status..

Project page says

> Provides basic functionalities and admin pages to handle deliveries.
>
> Each delivery need to be associated to an order. Each order can have
>   zero, one or multiple deliveries.
>
> A delivery is automatically created on order save if it contains at
>   least one shippable item. Further deliveries can be manually added
>   from the deliveries tab under the orders menu. On the same page each
>   order line item can be moved from one delivery to the other.

Comment: Thanx I am checking. :)

Comment: Not working as expected.